# creating hash table using perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to create hash table using perl. I have XML file as input and it contains information about diognostic tests and test description. Test number as a key and Test description as a value to the key. Then test number and string have the key -value relation.Help me to write perl script that stores description in one string and create hash table.please can help me because i am begginer to perl and i am reading but i am not able to implement.

```
 <DATA>
   <number>1</number>
   <age>24</age>
    <place>india</place>
    <description></description>
      </data>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve... There's a bunch of ways this data could be converted to "hash tables". Should all elements be key-value pairs? What to do with attributes? If you just need to read the file, consider using XML::Parser or XML::LibXML. Don't just try to shove it in "hash tables"......

Comment: `"can any one write the perl script to create hash table for below information."` ? Yes, anyone can, including yourself. You need to show us your attempt first though.

Comment: first of all thank you for your reply,sorry for my mistake, i am trying to create hash table like i have testnumber and test description and i am trying to store test description as a string and that string will be the value to the test number(key). test number as a key and test description(string)as a value.

Comment: Yes, but what have you tried?

Comment: like this i am reading file and extracted information but i dnt know how to store each test description into strings

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl
       use warnings;
       use strict;
 
       open(File1, "formal.xml") die "unable to open file: $!\n";
        open(File2, ">formal.xml") or die $!\n";
      while(<File1>)
      {
      chomp;
        print "$_\n";
       print File2 "$_\n";
        }
         close (File1);
       close(File2);

      while (<File>)
         {
       if (m|^\s*<DTC>| ... m|^\s*</DTC>|)
        {
          print;   
        }
        }

Answer (score 3):

That's pretty much what [XML::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aSimple) does. So just use that.